# Apache rewrite to 404 except for matched query

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to handle logically simple operation, but apache rewrite does not handle my website's query strings requests. I heard it's does not do it eventually. Still cannot understand it's regex syntax.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^\?category=([a-z])$ // WHY DO I NEED THIS?
RewriteRule ^!(?category=[a-z]+|?do=[a-z]+)$ [R=404,L,NC]
```

Goal is to send client to 404 for any query NOT matching /?category=[a-z]+ and /?do=[a-z]+. It would be much better if it's possible to load patterns from the text file.

Apache documentation is poor and Google does not help too.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need the `RewriteCond` because `RewriteRule`s only see the *path* portion of the URL, not the query string.  From [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> "**What is matched?**
>
> In `VirtualHost` context, The *Pattern* will initially be matched against the part of the URL after the hostname and port, and before the query string (e.g. "/app1/index.html").
>
> In `Directory` and htaccess context, the *Pattern* will initially be matched against the *filesystem*  path, after removing the prefix that lead the server to the current `RewriteRule` (e.g. "app1/index.html" or "index.html" depending on where the directives are defined).
>
> If you wish to match against the hostname, port, or query string, use a `RewriteCond` with the `%{HTTP_HOST}`, `%{SERVER_PORT}`, or `%{QUERY_STRING}` variables respectively."

I would also strongly recommend reading the "Per-directory Rewrites" box below that, since that's exactly what you're doing here.

One way to accomplish what you want might be like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/$  [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(category|do)=[a-z]+$
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L,NS]
```

Note how the `RewriteRule` simply matches everything, and the actual checks are done with the `RewriteCond`s.  The first `RewriteCond` matches if the path portion of the URI doesn't equal `/`; the second will match either if the first one did (because of the `OR` flag) or if the query string (sans `?`) doesn't match `category=[a-z]+` or `do=[a-z]+`.

(Note: I have not actually tested this code.  I *think* it should work as intended, but it's hard to be sure there are no bugs without testing.)